# How to make css not render div instead of just making it invisible?

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I know you can make the div invisible with css, but the fact that the div still exists is messing with the layout. How can I make it not render anything at all so the div does not exist?

Comment: Can you add some part of the code. Your question is defined but has no context

Comment: `document.getElementById("myDiv").Remove()`

Answer (score 4):

This is what I usually use and doesn't mess up my layout

```
div {
  display: none
}
```

Not sure if this is what you mean by "making it invisible".

Comment: Yes display none will remove it from the dom as opposed to using something else like visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 which the OP might be using but who knows ;)

Comment: @StefanBob thanks for the comment. Is it OK with you if I integrate it into the answer?

Comment: Sure thing @Daniel

Answer (score -1):

div will exist but not visible.

```
div {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```